# Flexbox ignoring justify-content, align-content, etc to eliminate gap between child elements

Tags: html, css, wordpress, flexbox, wordpress-gutenberg

I have searched extensively for an answer to this but keep hitting a brick wall. I have a Wordpress site I'm developing within the Gutenberg editor with a lot of custom styling. The whole front page is a series of flexboxes with child link elements. The children work fine and they are wrapping properly but there is a significant amount of space between them and I can't figure out where it is coming from. Setting the main wrapper flexbox to justify-content:center, justify-items:center, align-content:center, align-items:center, etc, simply has no effect on the spacing. For the larger items, this is fine. For the smaller items (at the bottom of the page), this means there are hundreds of pixels between them and it looks truly awful. The behavior I am looking for is to have the flexbox children in each row align to center with no gap between them at all.

You are welcome to see the page in its live environment -- https://july.avisato.com (the front page of the development site).

Here is the relevant section of code, I think.

```
<style>

*{text-transform:lowercase!important;}
html,head,body,img,a,ul,li,ol,section,span,p,section{border:0;margin:0;padding:0;list-style-type:none;}
html,body,img,div,span,p,ul,ol.li,td,a,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{font-family:"Cormorant Garamond",serif;text-decoration:none;font-weight:300;color:#000;line-height:1.3}
a:hover,a:active{text-decoration:none;}

.entry-content{display:flex;flex-wrap:wrap;}
.entry-content a{margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;}

.custom-logo{width:200px}




.text-en{}
.text-jp{font-family:"Noto Serif JP",serif;letter-spacing:-1px;}
.text-kr{font-family:"Noto Serif KR",serif;letter-spacing:-1px;}
.text-zh{font-family:"Noto Serif SC",serif;letter-spacing:-1px;}
.text-fr{font-style:italic;}






.clear{width:100%;height:1px!important;margin:0 0 -1px 0!important;padding:0!important;opacity:0;}

.frontpage-introtext{font-size:22px;padding:10px 30px;}
.frontpage-introtext p{margin-bottom:15px;}

.frontpage-grid-block{width:300px;height:290px;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:300px 290px;display:inline-flex;}

.frontpage-grid-block-1{background-image:url(/style/gridbg1.png);}
.frontpage-grid-block-2{background-image:url(/style/gridbg2.png);}
.frontpage-grid-block-3{background-image:url(/style/gridbg3.png);}
.frontpage-grid-block-4{background-image:url(/style/gridbg4.png);}
.frontpage-grid-block-5{background-image:url(/style/gridbg5.png);}
.frontpage-grid-block-6{background-image:url(/style/gridbg6.png);}
.frontpage-grid-block-7{background-image:url(/style/gridbg7.png);}
.frontpage-grid-block-8{background-image:url(/style/gridbg8.png);}
.frontpage-grid-block-9{background-image:url(/style/gridbg9.png);}

.frontpage-grid-element,.frontpage-grid2-element{display:inline-flex;flex-direction:column;align-items:flex-start;}

.frontpage-grid-element p{}

.frontpage-grid-element-1{margin-left:110px;margin-top:170px;}
.frontpage-grid-element-2{margin-left:145px;margin-top:150px;}
.frontpage-grid-element-3{margin-left:40px;margin-top:75px;}
.frontpage-grid-element-4{margin-left:100px;margin-top:30px;}
.frontpage-grid-element-5{margin-left:115px;margin-top:95px;}
.frontpage-grid-element-6{margin-left:170px;margin-top:100px;}
.frontpage-grid-element-7{margin-left:185px;margin-top:110px;}
.frontpage-grid-element-8{margin-left:70px;margin-top:130px;}
.frontpage-grid-element-9{margin-left:160px;margin-top:165px;}

.frontpage-grid2-block{height:140px;background-repeat:no-repeat;display:inline-flex;}
.frontpage-grid2-block-1{width:148px;background-size:148px 140px;background-image:url(/style/grid2bg1.png);}
.frontpage-grid2-block-2{width:187px;background-size:187px 140px;background-image:url(/style/grid2bg2.png);}
.frontpage-grid2-block-3{width:189px;background-size:189px 140px;background-image:url(/style/grid2bg3.png);}
.frontpage-grid2-block-4{width:152px;background-size:152px 140px;background-image:url(/style/grid2bg4.png);}
.frontpage-grid2-block-5{width:167px;background-size:167px 140px;background-image:url(/style/grid2bg5.png);}
.frontpage-grid2-block-6{width:166px;background-size:166px 140px;background-image:url(/style/grid2bg6.png);}
.frontpage-grid2-block-7{width:164px;background-size:164px 140px;background-image:url(/style/grid2bg7.png);}

.frontpage-grid2-element-1{margin-left:73px;margin-top:40px;}
.frontpage-grid2-element-2{margin-left:112px;margin-top:33px;}
.frontpage-grid2-element-3{margin-left:96px;margin-top:97px;}
.frontpage-grid2-element-4{margin-left:67px;margin-top:112px;}
.frontpage-grid2-element-5{margin-left:14px;margin-top:90px;}
.frontpage-grid2-element-6{margin-left:98px;margin-top:27px;}
.frontpage-grid2-element-7{margin-left:10px;margin-top:95px;}



</style>
```

The main section of the site is within the "entry-content" item and changing the properies of that definition in the css impact its behavior as expected except to align items or change their justification. The children are mostly  tags with text content and background images, which are relatively simple.

Yes, this will eventually become non-inline style but I want to make the thing work properly on this page first then worry about shifting it to a child template.

Thanks so much for any help!

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The code you've provided is pretty huge (it is not minimal) and there is no HTML except for `<style>` tags so it isn't enough to reproduce the problem. Follow the advice in [mcve]